# Generate download link from JSON data using Knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I have a `table`, which is dynamically filled using Knockout.js. The (somewhat simplified) body of the table looks like this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: results">
  <tr>
    <td id="resultTd">
      <a data-bind="attr: { href: ('api/results/' + instanceID + '/' + $data.name) }">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want the `a` tag to become a link to the file (typically a .doc) behind the generated table row. The problem is (you can assume the link etc. is set correctly) that the link returns JSON, which looks like this:

**JSON:**

```
{
   "version":{
      "major":1,
      "minor":1,
      "build":-1,
      "revision":-1,
      "majorRevision":-1,
      "minorRevision":-1
   },
   "content":{
      "headers":[
         {
            "key":"Content-Type",
            "value":[
               "application/octet-stream"
            ]
         },
         {
            "key":"Content-Disposition",
            "value":[
               "attachment; filename=foo.doc"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "statusCode":200,
   "reasonPhrase":"OK",
   "headers":[

   ],
   "requestMessage":null,
   "isSuccessStatusCode":true
}
```

As you can see, it contains an attachment "foo.doc" (let's assume this is the name `$data.name` generated).

My question is the following:
When I click the `td` element, I want to trigger a download prompt to download the file specified in the JSON.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This sounds like the problem is on the server end. Your JSON doesn't contain an attachement `foo.doc` it contains the *string* `foo.doc`. The server isn't actually returning the document at all.

Comment: @MattBurland Alright, guess I'll have to figure out how to get to the file.

Comment: You need the actual path to the file, wherever it's located on the file system on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Like Matt Burland said, the problem is on the server side. In my app I have a similar case where I have an `<a>` tag that has its href generated.

On the backend, you have to make sure to properly build your response so that the browser understands that you are currently downloading a file. For example this is a response header that my application has when I trigger a download of a word document:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 141312
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="I-C1-1.1%20MJ%20JB%20E%20(2012-07-16)%20.doc"
Charset: UTF-8
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-UA-Compatible: IE=8
Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 17:46:34 GMT
```

For the server side, here is the code I have for downloading the document (the response header I pasted)

```
FileStream fileStream = fileProvider.Open(filePath);
var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName);
response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
response.Content.Headers.Add("Charset", "UTF-8");
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileProvider.GetLength(filePath);//new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
return response;
```

For `response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName` you don't have to escape the filename unless you have special characters which is my case since our application manages French documents.

If you need any more explanations or have any comments on my answer, feel free to reply.

Comment: Altough this does not apply to my case, I feel like this answer may help others having a similar issue. Should I mark this as correct or only upvote?